# Allocated memory issue regarding reducing memory

Tags: android, performance

> how to reduce usage of the memory didn't found any solution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtQmU.png

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use the memory analyzer tool instead if will give the clear idea about allocation .

Thank you